# Does the inverse of Hölder's inequality holds?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Notation:
$$L^p_t L^q_x:= L^p(\mathbb{R},L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)),
\quad L^r_{t,x}:= L^r_t L^r_x$$

Hölder's inequality is one of the most fundamental tools in analysis.
That is, the following holds:
For all $f \in L^p_t L^q_x$ and $g \in L^{p'}_t L^{q'}_x$, the inequality
$$
\|fg\|_{L^1_{t,x}} \le \|f\|_{L^p_t L^q_x}\|g\|_{L^{p'}_t L^{q'}_x},
$$
holds, where $p,q \in [1,\infty]$, $1/p+1/p'=1$ and $1/q + 1/q'=1$.

I'm wondering whether the inverse of Hölder's inequality holds or not.
That is, the following statement is true or not?

> Let $p,q,p',q'$ satisfy the above condition.
> Then, for any $f \in L^1_{t,x}$,
> there exist $g \in L^p_t L^q_x$ and $h \in L^{p'}_t L^{q'}_x$
> such that $f=gh$ and $\|f\|_{L^1_{t,x}} = \|g\|_{L^p_t L^q_x} \|h\|_{L^{p'}_t L^{q'}_x}$

Comment: What is $\|fg\|_{L^1_{t,x}}$?

Comment: I mean $\|fg\|_{L^1_{t,x}}:= \|fg\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}, L^1(\mathbb{R}^d))}$. @geetha290krm

Comment: You should edit the question telling us exactly what $f$ and $g$ are. You should specify their domains/codomains

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I edited. Is this clear? @geetha290krm

Comment: Identical question on MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/428203/483536 . Please delete one of the post.

Comment: I'm sorry for posting similar questions. I deleted it.